# Need Help to create TabView for My Doodle App

Tags: android, layout

I am beginner in Android and developing one Doodle Application in which user can draw on the canvas.

For this i am providing one Relative Layout in which I am taking four Image Buttons for Selecting brushes size,Color and Make picture B/W and last one for Selecting photos from gallery.

Please help me out, how we will give various brushes option while clicking on brush ImageView button so that user can select whatever size they want.

Special thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can use fragment instead of Tab view.

[Fragment Android Developer](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html)

1. First you should extends a Fragment class.
2. Create a simple layout.
3. in onCreateView() in Fragment Class, return inflater.inflate(R.layout.my_layout, container, false);
4. You can simple use FragmentTransaction to switch them.

You can read the [example tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidFragments/article.html) for more information.